# Expire specific managed bean instance after time interval

Tags: jsf, scope, managed-bean

I have 2 JSF managed beans `A` and `B` and I need to expire/destruct/destroy `A` after 2 minutes and `B` after 5 minutes. I checked this related question [Timing out from a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581536/timing-out-from-a-bean), but it is expiring whole session. I do not want to expire whole session.

How can I achieve this with a custom scope?

Comment: You cant do that if the container is managing your beans

Comment: @Dummy they are JSF/manage bean **not** ejbs !! I am managing the scopes of JSF beans !!

Comment: Well you didnt say explicitly, you can use session beans as your jsf backing beans technically. If so, havent you thought about timer service?

Comment: Do you actually need to destroy them? Or is there a different usescase for which you think destroying them is the only solution? It's the first time in many years I hear this requirement

Comment: @Kukeltje I really want to destroy the beans.

Comment: Ok, good luck (sorry no idea how to do that other than creating a custom scope)

Comment: For such a requirement, I would create a custom scope (assuming you're using CDI) (sorry for the overlap @Kukeltje ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you're using JSF bean management facility (and thus not CDI, which would require a completely different answer), you can achieve this with [`@CustomScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/CustomScoped.html). The `@CustomScoped` value must refer a `Map` implementation in a broader, usually existing, scope.

Something like:

```
@ManagedBean
@CustomScoped("#{timeoutScope}")
public class TimeoutBean {}
```

As the `@CustomScoped` annotation doesn't support passing additional arguments, setting the timeout can only be done via an additional custom annotation like below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Timeout {

    /** Minutes. */
    int value();

}
```

```
@ManagedBean
@CustomScoped("#{timeoutScope}")
@Timeout(5) // Expires after 5 minutes.
public class TimeoutBean {}
```

Now, here's a kickoff example of how the `#{timeoutScope}` looks like, including `@PostConstruct` support (automatically) and `@PreDestroy` support (manually):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TimeoutScope extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object put(String name, Object bean) {
        Timeout timeout = bean.getClass().getAnnotation(Timeout.class);

        if (timeout == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("@Timeout annotation is required on bean " + name);
        }

        Long endtime = System.nanoTime() + (timeout.value() * (long) 6e10);
        Object[] beanAndEndtime = new Object[] { bean, endtime };
        return super.put(name, beanAndEndtime);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        Object[] beanAndEndtime = (Object[]) super.get(key);

        if (beanAndEndtime == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Object bean = beanAndEndtime[0];
        Long endtime = (Long) beanAndEndtime[1];

        if (System.nanoTime() > endtime) {
            String name = (String) key;
            ScopeContext scope = new ScopeContext("timeoutScope", Collections.singletonMap(name, bean));
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.getApplication().publishEvent(context, PreDestroyCustomScopeEvent.class, scope);
            return null;
        }

        return bean;
    }

}
```

You see, it's session scoped and implements `Map`. As to the scope, this way it's tied to a specific user session, not to the whole application. If you actually want to share the bean across all user sessions in the application, then make it application scoped instead. As to the `Map`, henever JSF needs to find a managed bean, it first tries `get()`. If it returns `null` (i.e. bean doesn't exist yet), then it will auto-create the managed bean instance and perform a `put()`.

Inside the `put()`, it's a matter of extracting and calculating the timeout and store it in the map. Inside the `get()`, you just check the timeout and return `null` to indicate JSF that bean doesn't exist anymore. JSF will then simply auto-create it and come back at `put()`, etc.

Do note that I'm using [`System#nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) instead of [`System#currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) as the latter is tied to OS (operating system) time, not to hardware time (and it's thus sensitive to a.o. DST and enduser-controlled changes in time).

Comment: So there is no way `@PreDestroy` support (automatically) ? I actually want that `@PreDestroy` calls as soon as bean's time ends !!

Comment: Perhaps you missed the updated answer or didn't actually try it or didn't read the code line by line?

Comment: Well I read your updated answer and code line-byline !! What I understand is that `@PreDestroy` support is manually **NOT** automatically !! Can it be **automatically**, like whenever Bean's time out it will call `get` or `@PreDestroy` automatically ?? Please let me know if I missed anything from your answer. Thanks

Comment: As a tip: Never use "!!" or "??", nor overuse bold formatting in formal English. This way you come over like a jerk and I'm very tempted to just delete the answer and ignore your future questions. As to the question in the comment, the code doesn't programmatically trigger `@PostConstruct` as that's already done by JSF automatically. The code only manually triggers `@PreDestroy` as that's not done by JSF automatically. The line with `publishEvent()` does that. Give it a try before asking new questions.

Comment: Thanks for reply and tip. I will take care of it in future.